# Externally generated projects(premake/cmake) lock up VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, premake

I'm using premake5 here.

It generates my solution/project files, when this happens, VS2015 asks me if I want to reload the modified projects.

If I hit yes, this proceeds to lock up the IDE for a very long time.
Anywhere from 30 seconds to 1 minute I'd say.

Does anyone know of a way to work around this? This is super irritating. 
It happens even for the most trivial of changes(modify one project, which only has 1 file in it).

I realize this is a VS problem, and not directly the fault of premake/cmake(or whatever build system you are using), but it totally sucks.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it's VS related :) But I think you have some problems with your installation : for small projects, reloading the whole solutions should be pretty fast : my personal projects take less than a second to reload (2 to 4 projects per solution, ~100 files per project)

Anyway in the usual course of development, re-generating your projects should not happen that often, except at the very beginning when you need to configure everything.

When you need to add a few files, just add them through Visual Studio : you won't have to run Premake again, and next time you run it, the files will be included by your script anyway. You can do the same with small configuration changes : update your project directly in VS, check that it works, and when it does, upadte the Premake script. You won't have to run Premake then.

Comment: do you put your .vcxproj files in the same directory as src files? I thought Id put them in a different location, but it turns out that this causes visual studio to place any new src files I generate in the directory of the .vcxproj, and not the directory that all the other src files are in:(

Comment: Visual Studio creates new source files where you tell it to. Be default, it's next to the project file, but you can change that location quite easily. I won't go into detail here, this is clearly related to using Visual Studio and not Premake.